# Call bitbake while bitbake is running

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Is it possible to run bitbake while bitbake is running? I'm starting `bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel` and would like to call `diffconfig` while I'm doing configuration. The best would be calling `bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel` from another window of tmux. But this currently gets a timeout. Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

For every sourced environment bitbake creates `bitbake.lock` and `bitbake.sock` files per build dir.

And in one build dir, you can't run bitbake while one bitbake is running.